# Is it possible to push from Fitbit to Fitocracy through RunKeeper?

Tags: synchronization, fitocracy, runkeeper, fitbit

I have a Fitbit device and synchronise with the website. My account on the Fitbit website is linked to Runkeeper, which has Read and Write access to my Fitbit profile. Runkeeper is connected to both Fitbit and Fitocracy. Fitocracy has Read and Write access to my Runkeeper account. My Fitocracy account confirms the connection to Runkeeper.

I currently log all my activity in the Fitbit web app (or Android app, sometimes) and sync it with that system. However, the only thing that gets pushed is a daily summary to Runkeeper. The messages are like "Thomas Owens burned 2,710 calories and took 12,102 steps over 1 day" - it's just a daily summary that appears to be pushed from Fitbit. Nothing is making it to Fitocracy at all (no daily summaries, no logged activities - absolutely nothing).

Is there some way to use my Fitbit and the Fitbit activity logging and have it publish all the way to Fitocracy?

Also, is it possible to have Fitbit log more details in Runkeeper (more than just a daily summary)?

Comment: When I sync bike rides from RunKeeper to Fitocracy, they're logged in RunKeeper as individual activities. I believe the piece you need to figure out is getting the FitBit to RunKeeper integration to log individual walk or run activities, instead of a daily summary.

Comment: @freiheit Thanks. That'll at least give me a starting point to try to figure out what's wrong or what I need to do, which is better than where I am now.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple activity syncer that copies Fitbit activities to Runkeeper.  It's available on https://activitysyncer.herokuapp.com/ .

Code is on https://github.com/fiddur/fitbit2runkeeper where any issues are tracked.  It's free and runs on a free Heroku account, so I don't give any guarantees, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

[According to RunKeeper](http://support.runkeeper.com/entries/21705487-Connecting-with-Fitbit), no. [You're not alone](https://www.facebook.com/Fitocracy/posts/575317379160407), I think many FitBit users would like to do this.